# MySQL - Revenue Current vs Prior Month

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if someone could help me workout MySQL version 5.7.22 script for retrieving current and previous month revenue in one table grouped by Date and AccountID

I have the following headers

- Date (last day of month)
- AccountID
- AccountName
- Revenue

Expected output example:

[image: expected results]

Due to the current version server etc I cannot use LAG or WITH.

EDIT:

- Current month revenue i can obtain
- I have multiple clients

Any help would be amazing

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select t.*, tprev.revenue
from t left join
     t tprev
     on extract(year_month from tprev.date) = extract(year_month from t.date - interval 1 month)
```

Comment: Thank you for this!
However think of me as a big time novice with MySQL so trying to understand this better.

If i have existing script as (there are other items on this table that i do not need to pull through with '*')

Select 

Date, 
AccountId, 
AccountName, 
Revenue

From Invoices

Group by Date,AccountID

where would i squeeze the above query you suggested

thanks in advance

Comment: @AfzalHussain . . . You would select only the columns you need.

Comment: @AfzalHussain . . . Your comment contains a bunch of tables that are not described in the question.  This answers the question asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.

Comment: Thanks you answer swinging some roundabout guided me to the right answer :D